# How to use a platform specific package in my R function

Tags: r, dependencies, bioconductor

my R package has a function (`my_func`) that uses function(`bar`) from another package (`foo`) which only available on Unix. So I write my code this way, following the [suggested packages in Writing R extension](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages):

```
my_func = function(){
....
  if (requireNamespace("foo", quietly = TRUE)) {
    foo::bar(..) # also tried bar(...)
  } else {
    # do something else without `bar`
  }
...
}
```

However, I keep getting such warning message when I run R CMD check:

'loadNamespace' or 'requireNamespace' call not declared from: foo

Is there any way to use platform specific packages without gives such warnings? I tried to include `foo` in the Description file and the warning disappeared, but then the package cannot be installed on windows because `foo` is not available for the win.

Comment: why do you want to install the package on windows if it needs functions only available in unix?

Comment: @qqq because otherwise, bioconductor won't accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread that comment, though it is easy to do because the logic is not clear and incontrovertible.

In that first paragraph that talked about calling packages using `require(package)` they said it was OK for a test environment or vignette but not from inside a finished function to use `library(package)` or `require(package)`.

This is considered bad form, because the packages you call inside a function will usurp the order of access your user has set up in her work environment when loading packages.

The method you use above:

`package::function()`

is the approved of way to use a function within a function without altering the current environment.

***But in order to use that function you must still have that package installed on your current machine or in your current working environment (such as a virtualenv or ipython or jupytr..and yes R will work in all those environments).***

You cannot run a function that R cannot see from the working environment...so you must have it installed, but not necessarily loaded, to call it.